# Need to speed up C++ code involving Boost multi-index and lookups to unordered_multimap

Tags: c++, boost, multimap, multi-index, unordered

I'm looking for strategies to speed up an agent-based model that's based on objects of class `Host`, pointers to which are stored in a Boost multi-index container. I've used Shark to determine that the vast majority of the time is consumed by a function `calcSI()`:

[image]

Function `calcSI()` has to compute for every instance of class `Host` certain probabilities that depend on attributes of other instances of class `Host`. (There are approximately 10,000-50,000 instances of `Host`, and these calculations are run for each host approximately 25,600 times.)

If I'm interpreting the profile correctly, the majority of the time spent in `calcSI()` goes to `Host::isInfectedZ(int)`, which simply counts instances of something in a Boost unordered_multimap of type `InfectionMap`:

```
struct Infection {
public:
  explicit Infection( double it, double rt ) : infT( it ), recT( rt ) {}
  double infT;
  double recT;
};
typedef boost::unordered_multimap< int, Infection > InfectionMap;
```

All members of `Host` contain `InfectionMap carriage`, and `Host::isInfectedZ(int)` simply counts the number of `Infections` associated with a  particular `int` key:

```
int Host::isInfectedZ( int z ) const {
  return carriage.count( z );
}
```

1. I'm having trouble finding information on how costly the `count` function is for Boost's unordered multimaps. Should I increase the overhead by adding to `Host` a separate two-dimensional array to track the number of instances of each key (i.e., the number of `Infections` associated with each `int`)?
2. I'm wondering if a larger structural overhaul of the Boost multi-index, like eliminating one or two less-needed composite key indices, would be more helpful. The background maintenance of the multi-index doesn't appear in the profiler, which (maybe stupidly) makes me worry it might be large. I have 8 indices in the multi-index, most of which are ordered_non_unique.
3. Are there other things I should be concerned with that might not appear in the profiler, or am I missing a major result from the profiler?

Parallelization and multithreading of `calcSI()` are unfortunately not options.

*Update:* It might be helpful to know that `InfectionMap carriage` rarely has more than 10 pairs and usually has <5.

---

*Update 2:* I tried the strategy proposed in #1 above, giving each `Host` an array `int carriageSummary[ INIT_NUM_STYPES ]`, which is indexed by the possible values of `z` (for most simulations, there are <10 possible values). The value of each entry tracks changes made to `carriage`. The `Host::isInfectedZ( int z )` function now reads:

```
int Host::isInfectedZ( int z ) const {
  //return carriage.count( z );
  return carriageSummary[ z ];
}
```

And the time dedicated to this function *appears* to have dropped substantially--I can't do an exact comparison right now:
[image] 
**Obviously, using an array is kind of bulky but okay for small ranges of `z`. Would some other container (i.e., not an unordered_map) be more efficient for larger ranges?**

Would love any feedback on changing multi-index too.

Comment: What is the range of integers that can be passed into Host::isInfected?

Comment: @Emile: The range goes from 0 to `const int INIT_NUM_STYPES - 1`. Most of the time (i.e., in most simulations) `INIT_NUM_STYPES = 4` but sometimes I set it as high as 8 or 10. In other words, `Host::isInfectedZ(int z)` normally has `z` = 0, 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: This is a perfect example of using pre-exiting containers and algorithms for making life simple and code easy to read. It's profiling that tells you when you need to start working closer to the bare metal with pointers and c-style arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you suggested in #1, try maintaining a carriage count array next to the Host::carriage unordered_multimap and keep them both "synchronised". Your Host::isInfectedZ would then use the (hopefully) faster carriage count array:

```
int Host::isInfectedZ( int z ) const {
  return carriageCount[ z ];
}
```

If the range of integers that can be passed into isInfected is large, then use an associative array for your carriage count.

You can use std::map or boost::unordered for the associative array. For lookups, the former has logarithmic temporal complexity and the latter has constant temporal complexity. But since this associative array would be typically very small, std::map might actually be faster. std::map may also take up less space overhead. Try both and run your profiler to see. My bet is on std::map. :-)

EDIT:

Upon seeing your answer to my comment, I would suggest using a regular fixed-size array for the carriage count. Forget about the associative array stuff.

EDIT2:

You might want to scrap

```
typedef boost::unordered_multimap< int, Infection > InfectionMap;
```

and roll-up your own hand-written InfectionMap class, since you're dealing with such small indices.

RESPONSE TO UPDATE #2:

Glad to see you've made an improvement. I doubt you'll find an container that is "less bulky" than a fixed array of, say, 16 integers. STL and boost containers allocate memory in chunks and will end up as large as your fixed-size array, even if they have few elements.

You might be interested in boost::array, which wraps an STL-like interface around a C-style fixed array. This will make it easier to "swap-out" your fixed-size array for a std::vector or std::map.

Comment: Thanks, I was making my update #2 as you were writing this answer. The plain old array is working fine for now, but I really appreciate your offering suggestions for situations with a larger range of `z`. I'll update this post (maybe in a few days to a week) when I get around to testing bigger ranges with `std::map`. Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about it unless you're running into memory problems. It's perfectly normal to trade off memory for extra speed -- your case warrants it, as proven by your benchmarks.